# Unable to Install package from Ubuntu Xenial local repo

Tags: apt, 16.04, repository, apt-mirror, localrepository

I created a local repo for Xenial using apt-mirror.

When I tried `sudo apt-get update` in another machine (of course, I configured the webserver), I am getting the following errors and I am not able to install any package from the local repo. What can be done?

```
$ sudo apt-get update 
Get:1 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial InRelease [247 kB]
Get:2 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [94.5 kB]
Get:3 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [94.5 kB]
Get:4 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-proposed InRelease [247 kB]
Get:5 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [92.2 kB]
Ign:6 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:7 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages
Ign:8 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial/universe Translation-en
Ign:9 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:10 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:11 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:12 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:13 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:14 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:15 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:16 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:17 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:18 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial/restricted Translation-en
Ign:19 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:20 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:21 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:22 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:23 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:24 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Get:6 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages [7,532 kB]
Ign:7 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages
Get:8 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial/universe Translation-en [4,354 kB]
Ign:9 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:10 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Get:11 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages [1,201 kB]
Ign:12 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages  
Get:13 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en [568 kB]
Ign:14 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:15 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Get:16 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 Packages [8,344 B]
Ign:17 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial/restricted i386 Packages
Get:18 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial/restricted Translation-en [2,908 B]
Ign:19 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Get:20 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial/multiverse amd64 Packages [144 kB]
Ign:21 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:22 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:23 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:24 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:25 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:26 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages
Ign:27 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-updates/main Translation-en
Ign:28 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:29 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:30 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:31 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign:32 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe Translation-en
Ign:33 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:34 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:35 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:36 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:37 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted Translation-en
Ign:38 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:39 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:40 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:41 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:42 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:43 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
Ign:44 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-security/main i386 Packages
Ign:45 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-security/main Translation-en
Ign:46 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:47 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:48 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:49 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-security/universe i386 Packages
Ign:50 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-security/universe Translation-en
Ign:51 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:52 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:53 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:54 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:55 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted Translation-en
Ign:56 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:57 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:58 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:59 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:60 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:61 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-proposed/main amd64 Packages
Ign:62 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-proposed/main i386 Packages
Ign:63 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-proposed/main Translation-en
Ign:64 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-proposed/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:65 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-proposed/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:66 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-proposed/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:67 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-proposed/universe i386 Packages
Ign:68 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-proposed/universe Translation-en
Ign:69 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-proposed/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:70 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-proposed/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:71 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-proposed/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:72 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-proposed/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:73 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-proposed/restricted Translation-en
Ign:74 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-proposed/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:75 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-proposed/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:76 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-proposed/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:77 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-proposed/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:78 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-proposed/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:79 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-proposed/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:7 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages
Ign:80 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 Packages
Ign:81 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-backports/main i386 Packages
Ign:82 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-backports/main Translation-en
Ign:83 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:84 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:85 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe i386 Packages
Ign:86 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe Translation-en
Ign:87 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:88 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:89 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-backports/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:90 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-backports/restricted Translation-en
Ign:91 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-backports/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:92 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:93 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:94 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:95 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-backports/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Err:9 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  404  Not Found
Err:10 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
  404  Not Found
Ign:12 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Err:14 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  404  Not Found
Err:15 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
  404  Not Found
Ign:17 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial/restricted i386 Packages
Err:19 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  404  Not Found
Ign:21 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial/multiverse i386 Packages
Get:22 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial/multiverse Translation-en [131 kB]
Err:23 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  404  Not Found
Err:24 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons
  404  Not Found
Get:25 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages [93.9 kB]
Ign:26 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages
Get:27 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-updates/main Translation-en [39.9 kB]
Ign:28 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:29 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Get:30 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages [32.1 kB]
Ign:31 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages
Get:32 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe Translation-en [18.9 kB]
Ign:33 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:34 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Get:35 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [64 B]
Ign:36 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Get:37 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted Translation-en [64 B]
Ign:38 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Get:39 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [1,176 B]
Ign:40 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Get:41 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse Translation-en [628 B]
Ign:42 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Get:43 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages [52.6 kB]
Ign:44 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-security/main i386 Packages
Get:45 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-security/main Translation-en [20.6 kB]
Ign:46 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:47 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Get:48 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages [9,904 B]
Ign:49 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-security/universe i386 Packages
Get:50 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-security/universe Translation-en [7,576 B]
Ign:51 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:52 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Get:53 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted amd64 Packages [64 B]
Ign:54 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted i386 Packages
Get:55 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted Translation-en [64 B]
Ign:56 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Get:57 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [1,176 B]
Ign:58 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Get:59 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse Translation-en [628 B]
Ign:60 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Get:61 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-proposed/main amd64 Packages [137 kB]
Ign:62 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-proposed/main i386 Packages
Get:63 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-proposed/main Translation-en [50.7 kB]
Ign:64 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-proposed/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:65 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-proposed/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Get:66 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-proposed/universe amd64 Packages [70.6 kB]
Ign:67 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-proposed/universe i386 Packages
Get:68 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-proposed/universe Translation-en [28.8 kB]
Ign:69 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-proposed/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:70 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-proposed/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Get:71 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-proposed/restricted amd64 Packages [64 B]
Ign:72 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-proposed/restricted i386 Packages
Get:73 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-proposed/restricted Translation-en [64 B]
Ign:74 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-proposed/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Get:75 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-proposed/multiverse amd64 Packages [64 B]
Ign:76 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-proposed/multiverse i386 Packages
Get:77 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-proposed/multiverse Translation-en [64 B]
Ign:78 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-proposed/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:79 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-proposed/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Get:80 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 Packages [672 B]
Ign:81 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-backports/main i386 Packages
Get:82 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-backports/main Translation-en [528 B]
Ign:83 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Get:84 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 Packages [64 B]
Ign:85 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe i386 Packages
Get:86 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe Translation-en [64 B]
Ign:87 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Get:88 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-backports/restricted amd64 Packages [64 B]
Ign:89 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-backports/restricted i386 Packages
Get:90 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-backports/restricted Translation-en [64 B]
Ign:91 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-backports/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Get:92 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages [64 B]
Ign:93 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
Get:94 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-backports/multiverse Translation-en [64 B]
Ign:95 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-backports/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Err:12 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err:17 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err:21 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign:26 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages
Err:28 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  404  Not Found
Err:29 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
  404  Not Found
Ign:31 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages
Err:33 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  404  Not Found
Err:34 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
  404  Not Found
Ign:36 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Err:38 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  404  Not Found
Ign:40 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Err:42 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  404  Not Found
Ign:44 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-security/main i386 Packages
Err:46 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  404  Not Found
Err:47 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
  404  Not Found
Ign:49 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-security/universe i386 Packages
Err:51 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  404  Not Found
Err:52 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
  404  Not Found
Ign:54 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted i386 Packages
Err:56 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  404  Not Found
Ign:58 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Err:60 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  404  Not Found
Ign:62 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-proposed/main i386 Packages
Err:64 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-proposed/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  404  Not Found
Err:65 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-proposed/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
  404  Not Found
Ign:67 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-proposed/universe i386 Packages
Err:69 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-proposed/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  404  Not Found
Err:70 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-proposed/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
  404  Not Found
Ign:72 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-proposed/restricted i386 Packages
Err:74 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-proposed/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  404  Not Found
Ign:76 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-proposed/multiverse i386 Packages
Err:78 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-proposed/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  404  Not Found
Err:79 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-proposed/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons
  404  Not Found
Ign:81 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-backports/main i386 Packages
Err:83 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  404  Not Found
Ign:85 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe i386 Packages
Err:87 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  404  Not Found
Ign:89 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-backports/restricted i386 Packages
Err:91 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-backports/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  404  Not Found
Ign:93 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
Err:95 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-backports/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  404  Not Found
Err:31 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err:36 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err:40 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err:49 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-security/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err:54 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err:58 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err:67 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-proposed/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err:72 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-proposed/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err:76 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-proposed/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err:85 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err:89 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-backports/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err:93 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Fetched 775 kB in 1s (556 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/xenial/universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/xenial/universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/xenial/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/xenial/restricted/dep11/Components-amd64.yml  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/xenial/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/xenial/multiverse/dep11/Components-amd64.yml  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/xenial/multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64.tar  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/restricted/dep11/Components-amd64.yml  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/multiverse/dep11/Components-amd64.yml  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/restricted/dep11/Components-amd64.yml  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/multiverse/dep11/Components-amd64.yml  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/xenial-proposed/main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/xenial-proposed/main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/xenial-proposed/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/xenial-proposed/universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/xenial-proposed/universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/xenial-proposed/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/xenial-proposed/restricted/dep11/Components-amd64.yml  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/xenial-proposed/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/xenial-proposed/multiverse/dep11/Components-amd64.yml  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/xenial-proposed/multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64.tar  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/restricted/dep11/Components-amd64.yml  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://172.16.3.37/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/multiverse/dep11/Components-amd64.yml  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead
```

Comment: How'd you create the local repository? Did you fully sync up with the Ubuntu Archive mirrors (we're talking I believe terabytes of data) before attempting to use the local repo?

Comment: I have created a local repo using "apt-mirror" with the following lines in the "\etc\apt\mirror.list" 

deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse free non-free
deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse free non-free
deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse free non-free

Comment: I have updated and re-posted the question here [http://askubuntu.com/questions/786733/apt-get-update-command-not-working-from-xenial-local-mirror]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your local package repository is out of sync, or your package *list* of what to install is out of sync.

404 Not Found means the packages aren't available in the repository that the system wants, so you only have a few options here.

**If the repository is out of sync:**

Resync your repository with the main ones, run `apt-get update` as normal on the system that uses it, after the sync is finished.

**If resyncing the repository doesn't work:**

Tell the computer to use `archive.ubuntu.com` (or one of its country mirror) servers for getting updates.

Comment: I have used a 32-bit Ubuntu 14.04 machine to download the repository using "apt-mirror". Then tried to update a 64-bit Ubuntu 16.04 machine using this as a local repository. Unfortunately, I am not able to connect my 64-bit machine directly to Internet (hence I cannot tell my computer to use archive.ubuntu.com) servers directly !

Comment: I have updated and re-posted the question here [http://askubuntu.com/questions/786733/apt-get-update-command-not-working-from-xenial-local-mirror]