# apt-get update command not working from xenial local mirror

Tags: apt, software-installation, 16.04, localrepository

Using apt-mirror, I downloaded the xenial packages to my machine (ip address: 172.16.3.37). 
The content of my "mirror.list" for apt-mirror is the  following.

```
############# config ##################
#
 set base_path    /ubuntuRepo
#
# set mirror_path  $base_path/mirror
# set skel_path    $base_path/skel
# set var_path     $base_path/var
# set cleanscript $var_path/clean.sh
# set defaultarch  <running host architecture>
# set postmirror_script $var_path/postmirror.sh
# set run_postmirror 0
set nthreads     20
set _tilde 0
#
############# end config ##############



deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse free non-free
deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse free non-free
deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse free non-free
deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-proposed main restricted universe multiverse free non-free
deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse free non-free


deb-i386 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse free non-free
deb-i386 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse free non-free
deb-i386 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse free non-free
deb-i386 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-proposed main restricted universe multiverse free non-free
deb-i386 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse free non-free
```

The files were successfully downloaded.

I tried to install packages using this repo from another machine.
That machine's /etc/apt/sources.list contains the following line (I intentionally kept only one line to reduce the number of  errors).

```
    deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse free non-free
```

Now, when I try "apt-get update" I am getting the following.

```
Get:1 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntuRepo/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease [247 kB]
Ign:2 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntuRepo/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:3 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntuRepo/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:4 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntuRepo/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:5 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntuRepo/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:6 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntuRepo/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:7 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntuRepo/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:8 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntuRepo/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages
Ign:9 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntuRepo/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe Translation-en
Ign:10 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntuRepo/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:11 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntuRepo/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Get:2 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntuRepo/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages [1,201 kB]
Get:3 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntuRepo/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages [1,196 kB]
Get:4 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntuRepo/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en [568 kB]
Ign:5 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntuRepo/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:6 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntuRepo/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Get:7 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntuRepo/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages [7,532 kB]
Get:8 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntuRepo/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages [7,512 kB]
Get:9 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntuRepo/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe Translation-en [4,354 kB]
Ign:10 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntuRepo/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:11 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntuRepo/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Err:5 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntuRepo/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  404  Not Found
Err:6 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntuRepo/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
  404  Not Found
Err:10 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntuRepo/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  404  Not Found
Err:11 http://172.16.3.37/ubuntuRepo/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
  404  Not Found
Fetched 247 kB in 0s (574 kB/s) 
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://172.16.3.37/ubuntuRepo/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://172.16.3.37/ubuntuRepo/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://172.16.3.37/ubuntuRepo/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://172.16.3.37/ubuntuRepo/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I had asked a similar question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/777277/unable-to-install-package-from-ubuntu-xenial-local-repo).
Any helpful thought is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem. For me the solution was:

```
rm /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50appstream
```

The source:
[Ubuntu 16.04 apt-get update doesn't work with local repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/771547/ubuntu-16-04-apt-get-update-doesnt-work-with-local-repository)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your repository mirrors only amd64 packages, but your system wants both amd64 and i386 packages. Just add `deb-i386` lines similar to the `deb-amd64` ones you already have, and sync the mirror again.

Comment: I addded "deb-i386" lines.

Comment: I have added the "deb-i386" lines and still it is not working. I have updated my post using this information.

Comment: @user4661268 the DEP-11 lines are a separate issue and a known bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt-mirror/+bug/1550852 You can ignore those errors, it doesn't affect the working at all.