# Problems setting up local apt-mirror for 16.04

Tags: apt, 16.04, apt-mirror

I have an local apt-mirror server for a while that contains 12.04 and 14.04.

this server itself runs 12.04.

I tried to add 16.04 repo and I'm facing issues with it:

First of all, when I try `sudo apt-get update` on one of the clients (which runs 16.04) I got the following errors:

```
Failed to fetch http://mydomain/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml 404 Not Found
Failed to fetch http://mydomain/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml 404 Not Found
Failed to fetch http://mydomain/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml 404 Not Found
```

I searched it for a while and I encountered those:

[apt-get update command not working from xenial local mirror](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786733/apt-get-update-command-not-working-from-xenial-local-mirror]) - I removed the file (on client side, maybe I should do it on the server side?) but it didn't solve the problem. There is also one comment there that states that this errors can be ignored, so I ignored them and try to install stuff but it seems to be broken - it failed to find `vim`, `openssh-server` so I stopped there.

There is also this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt-mirror/+bug/1550852 which seems to be related but I'm not sure if it was solved if it does what should I do with my apt-mirror server.

Any ideas?